# How to separate string between semicolon and count length

Tags: python, pandas

In a `pandas` data frame is there anyway to split a column by '; ' and count the string length, like in this example:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123; 345 | 3; 3 |
| 54; 8903 | 2; 4 |

the result should be in an XLSX file.

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    valid0 = row['Part_Number']
    valid1 = valid0.split('; ')
    valid1 = [len(i) for i in valid1[:]]
    valid2 = str(valid1)
    valid3 = ''.join(valid2)
    df1['Part_Number_valid'] = df1['Part_Number'].replace({valid0:valid3})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
df['col3']=df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join([str(len(i)) for i in x.split('; ')]))

'''
    Col1        col3
0   123; 345    3; 3
1   54; 8903    2; 4


'''
```